# Debugging cURL request with NetBeans while the server processes another request is not working

Tags: php, curl, netbeans

I have a rest server and a client. The client sends request, which I can debug. But while the server is processing the request, the client runs a console command that is sending another request via cURL. Is it possible to debug both requests, because my cURL request is hanging. At the end I have the following error:

> Curl error requesting "http://my-host.com": #28 - Operation timed out after 30014 milliseconds with 0 bytes received`

I have the latest version of NetBeans and I am using xDebug.